# Why is my Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse resulting in Error Not Found?

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I upgraded Eclipse and moved to Google Cloud Platform for Eclipse for my existing Standard App Engine project. I also moved to Java 8.

Now, when I deploy my app, the size shown in the console is only 7.1mb vs. 220mb prior to the upgrade. And when I try to go to the app after deployment I get an Error: Not Found message.

Is there something in the setup for my new configuration that would be causing this?

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is indeed somewhat broad; you'll need to provide all necessary detail. A correspondingly [general information page](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/how-to) might help here, though, namely Eclipse "How-to Guides". 
Have you adapted and re-written your app for Java 8? If so, in which way? Have you edited your app.yaml configuration file accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Tools for Eclipse writes out the app-to-be-deployed to a directory in your workspace called `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/com.google.cloud.tools.eclipse.appengine.deploy/tmp/<timestamp>/staging-work/exploded-war`, where `<timestamp>` is the time of the last two deploys.  Look at the `exploded-war` directory and see what files are missing.  You may then get a better sense of what needs to be remediated.